# Uninsulated concrete garage floors in cold climate

Tags: concrete

It's not uncommon to see uninsulated concrete garage floors in cold climates. Some of these floors, however, crack and rise like Mt. Everest from the frost action while others remain crack-free and flat as pool tables over time. Would this difference be explained by the underlying base on which the concrete sits?  In other words, are gravel bases sufficient to ward off frost action on uninsulated concrete garage floors in cold climates?

Comment: Rebar. Water diversion/shedding helps as well. Concrete floors that heave are structurally unsound from day 1.

Comment: I've owned and lived with unheated/uninsulated garages in an extreme climate zone for 30 years. I rarely see movement inside a garage. There's usually enough ground heat and the soil is usually dry enough (near the surface) that frost doesn't cause problems. Yes, gravel or sand is usually sufficient, but conditions vary.

Comment: This is a rather broad and hypothetical question. Can you refine it to be more specific at all? Questions should seek to solve a particular problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes, if the underlying soil is susceptible to frost action, the depth of the gravel base is very important, as the moisture of the soil will rise to the surface through capillary action and become freezing (volume expand) that pushing against the slab. For a trouble-free cold floor, the coarse base material should be no less than 8" (my opinion) to cut off the water passages.

Comment: It's only the water under the base that causes problems. If the base isn't thick enough, and there's a layer of water under, there's going to be problems. Gravel underneath is a mixed blessing: if it allows water to drain away, it's good. If it retains water, because there's nowhere for that water to drain off, it's bad.